# “Close and Halt” feature does not functioning in jupyter notebook launched under Canopy on macOs High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, macos-high-sierra, canopy

When I done with my work, I try to close my jupyter notebook via 'Close and Halt' under the file menu. However it somehow do not functioning.

I am running the notebook from Canopy, version: 2.1.9.3717, under macOs High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Jupyter notebook from Canopy, then the Jupyter notebook interface is not controlling the kernel; rather, Canopy's built-in ipython Qtconsole is. You can restart the kernel from the Canopy run menu.

Comment: Actually, I would like to close the jupyter notebook properly. I dont like to leave it running in the background. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want a jupyter kernel process that is independent of the Canopy GUI, then start the notebook from a Canopy Terminal (from the Canopy Tools menu). When you stop that, it will be fully closed.